# What is this fantasy book that had orbs as a central plot device?

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to remember the title of a series I read years ago. A young girl, whose father disappeared mysteriously, somehow comes into possession of an orb. These orbs are part machine and part magic, notoriously difficult to learn to use, and have a penchant for breaking after they are used too much. The orb she has is more powerful and lasts longer than any orb should. It also appears to have a personality of its own, as it saves her and helps her without her direction. She slowly comes to realize that her father’s soul is in the orb, and that’s how he mysteriously disappeared.

This is just the synopsis of the orb part of the story. I forget so much of the actual plot. But maybe someone has heard of this same series before (or more recently)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.  For example, do you remember anything about what the cover looked like?

Comment: Some elements are similar to the Fall of Ile-Rien series starting with the Wizard Hunters by Martha Wells. Tremaine is an adult (20s) and the sphere doesn't contain her father, but...that would be a spoiler. Technology is early 20th century level. Guns and airships, magic/sorcery is real.